# Роут link-to копирует параметры запроса (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, route, handlebars, ember.js

Например имеется роут `groups` выводящий соответственно список всех групп. Если у роута есть параметры, например, `groups?grouptype=new`, то он, например, выводит список новых групп. Т.е. суть в том что наполнение страницы меняется от наличия параметра.

В таком случае появляется непредвиденная проблема. 
Есть статичная ссылка на роут через `link-to`, например:

```
{{#link-to 'groups'}}
```

то находясь по адресу `groups?grouptype=new`, `link-to` генерирует такую ссылку

```
<a href="/groups?grouptype=new"></a>
```

Почему так, и можно ли избавиться от параметров в ссылке?

Answer (score 0):

Найдено примерно такое решение:

1. Сделать как [здесь](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-can-i-reset-sticky-query-params/14522)
2. В роуте, где используются параметры, прописать для каждого используемого параметра это:

   `queryParams: {
     your_params1: {
       refreshModel: true
     },
     your_params2: {
       refreshModel: true
     }
   }`
3. Если в роуте проводятся какие-либо манипуляции над полями контроллера при наличии параметра, их необходимо сбрасывать в исходное состояние вручную при его отсутствии